# How to display multiple returned value of a function in .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, function, data-structures, return

I have the following Structure

```
Public Structure Info_Diag_Data
    Public DataOne As String
    Public DataTwo As String
End Structure
```

And this function uses the above class

```
Public Shared Function My_Function(ByVal RcvVal As Integer) As Info_Diag_Data

    Dim SendVal As Info_Diag_Data

    Select Case RcvVal
        Case 1
            SendVal.DataOne = "Red"
            SendVal.DataTwo = "Master"
        Case 2
            SendVal.DataOne = "Red"
            SendVal.DataTwo = "Teacher"
    End Select

    Return SendVal
End Function
```

Now i know i can execute this function using `My_Function(2)`

My question is how to display this data after getting these two returned values from function.

Like as i got `DataOne` and `DataTwo` in return. Then how can i show it in `MessageBox.Show(DataOne)` and `MessageBox.Show(DataTwo)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to store the results in a `Info_Diag_Data` value, then you'll be able to access the various members of the object through that variable, like this:

```
Dim data As Info_Diag_Data = My_Function(2)
MessageBox.Show(data.DataOne)
MessageBox.Show(data.DataTwo)
```